# How to solve this linear recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

how to solve following recurrence relation :

> $f(n) = 3 * f(n - 1) + 4$

i've got that recurrence relation from following sequence, where f(n) is nth value of the following sequence.

> $7, 25, 79, 241, 727, 2185$, and so on.

So $f(0) = 7$, $f(1) = 25$. etc.

Comment: Hint: add something to both sides and make a well-known, simpler sequence.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Where do you feel like you're struggling? We can help you better once we know where the issue is ^_^

Comment: @NeatMath I'm not aware of well known simpler sequences. can you please give an example of how would you simplify it?

Comment: $g(n)=3 *g(n-1)$ would be simpler.  Try adding $2$ to both sides of your relation

Comment: NeatMath ,j W Tanner thank you. i've realized it now.
. @HallaSurvivor thank you :) I'm trying to develop iterative algorithm for modified version of Ackermann Function which is defined in recursive terms. I want to evaluate it for large value of n. Doing it with recursive approach is easy but that is busting out programs 'call stack' even for n = 4 and now i know it why.

Answer (score 1):

The hint from [Neat Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/843178/neat-math) suggests $f(n)=3f(n-1)+4\iff f(n)+2=3(f(n-1)+2)$

or $g(n)=3g(n-1)$ where $g(n)=f(n)+2$, so $g(n)=3^{n}g(0)$, with $g(0)=9$,

so $g(n)=3^{n+2}$, so $f(n)=3^{n+2}-2$.

A more pedantic solution would be the following:

$f(n)-3f(n-1)=f(n-1)-3f(n-2)$, so $f(n)=4f(n-1)-3f(n-2)$.

The roots of the characteristic equation $r^2=4r-3$ are $r=1,3$,

so the solution is $f(n)=A\cdot3^n+B\cdot1^n$.

Solve for $A$ and $B$ given $f(0)=7$ and $f(1)=25$.